# Html pages not loaded from application cache when used jquery .load('pageName') method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am trying to implement  the `html5 offline cache` feature  of our html pages, it works fine for the `jquery version 1.4`.

But when  i used the jquery 1.8, the problem arises for the html pages which i loaded by using the jquery method of `load()`. i.e;

```
$('#divName').load('htmlPageName')
{
   // some functionailty
}
```

**The HTML is not rendered**. It seems all the pages are downloaded so, there is no issue in caching. Other pages work fine if we not used `.load()`

Comment: did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Give an  extension of the htmlpagename and if you need callback function you can have `$("#divName").load('htmlPageName','',myFunc);`
and you can have whatever you want to achieve  in  this particular function

function myFunc(){
    }

Comment: have you given the .html extension?